# Error using using DLL Import in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-c++

I had a sample application in C++ just to test out the DLL Export/Import stuff. The dll is built from Visual C++ project.
Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLLFunctionExposeTest.h"

extern "C" DLLFUNCTIONEXPOSETEST_API int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

WPF code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLLImportTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int e = 3, f = 4;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int g = fnSumofTwoDigits(e, f); //exception
        }
    [DllImport("DLLFunctionExposeTest.dll")]
    private static extern int fnSumofTwoDigits(int a, int b);
}
}
```

When I try to run this application, I get an error saying - XamlParseException was unhandled.

`The invocation of the constructor on type 'DLLImportTest.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.`
On handling the exception, this is the prompt:

`Unbale to find entrypoint named fnSumofTwoDigits in the DLL`
Any suggestions on what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post the inner exception, i.e. the exception thrown by the call to `fnSumofTwoDigits`?

Comment: @Justin: I have this built dll in my WPF `$SolutionDir` i.e bin/debug folder of WPF solution. How do I find the inner exception from here?

Comment: Hi Cipher, put the InitializeComponent() method inside a try..catch... block to have a more detailed error.

Comment: @Angelodev: Here is the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EAFQW.png

Comment: take a look there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049030/c-sharp-call-a-c-dll-get-entrypointnotfoundexception 

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465243/cannot-call-dll-import-entry-c-sharp-c-entrypointnotfoundexception

Comment: @Angelodev: But my C++ dll project has these functions alone, and not instance functions of any class as in the above code. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049030/c-sharp-call-a-c-dll-get-entrypointnotfoundexception , the dll should not have instance functions as in that example. :-/
extern "C" is prepended in my functions as well.